# jhipster 4 angular 4: how call selector in pahe html?

Tags: java, angular, components, selector, jhipster

I have one problem, have created a new entity with `jhipster: entity`.
Now I want to integrate it into another screen. And with the main component selector:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-motif-absence-tsd-paie',
    templateUrl: './motif-absence-tsd-paie.component.html'
})
```

i call selector  in html page  : `<jhi-typeAbsence-tsd-paie></jhi-typeAbsence-tsd-paie>`
but it is not working.

thank you for your help

Comment: `jhi-typeAbsence-tsd-paie`  this selector is not there in component.

Comment: my problem is Angular module not available to Allow importing of multiple Angular modules in jhipster . have u idea?